# Verb/noun/adjective/adverb table

Tags: dictionaries

I'm looking for a resource in which I can look up for a verb, noun, adjective or adverb and get its corresponding verb, noun, adjective or adverb.

Something like [this](https://www.worldclasslearning.com/english/list-of-verbs-nouns-adjectives-adverbs.html), only much larger — this table only has 127 entries.

I have consulted the meta question [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735) and it doesn't seem to include anything similar.

Online dictionaries are often insufficient in fulfilling this need. For instance, just now I wanted to find the verb corresponding to the word *contagious* and since one doesn't exist, I had to research to reach this conclusion. On the other hand, the absence of the word in the dictionary doesn't guarantee that there isn't a corresponding word.

Comment: I was going to comment that I couldn't find an adequate tag for this question, but then I realized that as per [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), my question is off-topic. Since I'm not a registered user, I'm unable to delete it. Feel free to do it.

Comment: I realize that the word _infect_ could serve the same purpose as a verb for _contagious_, but that's not the point of the question.

Comment: If some charitable soul can share a resource like the one I'm looking for while the question is still live, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.